# Should the <main> tag be inside <section> tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Should `<main>` be considered something important to put inside `<section>`? Like having many articles with `<main>` 'article' in `<section>`? If not then how to use them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) again:

> Authors are advised to use ARIA role="main" attribute on the main
> element until user agents implement the required role mapping.

[HTML5 doctor, though somewhat outdated, does provide a useful working example of the `main` element](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/):

```
<main id="content" class="group">
    <!-- [...] -->
</main>
```

In short, the `main` element should be used whenever possible (but only once per page).  Alternatively, you can use `role="main"` on a sectioning element with the exact same results in terms of WAI-ARIA.  [Read more about WAI-ARIA roles in my post](https://seangoresht.com/blog/post/design-for-the-blind-design-for-the-future).  For example:

```
<div class="main-content-column">
    <article role="main" id="content">
        [...]
    </article>
</div>
```

I don't see how assigning the `role="main"` to a `section` element could be semantic at all, but there may be use cases.  Generally, you'll want to use the `article` tag to identify `main` content.  The above snippet provides the exact same semantic information as `<main>` (note that declaring `role="main"` on a `<main>` element is not required by modern screen readers and user agents).

Comment: This answer is outdated, do not add role="main" to main tags. [ARIA specifically warns about this use case](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#avoid-specifying-redundant-roles), since it is redundant. The [HTML5 Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) mentioned here no longer has the stated advise.

Answer (score 9):

From the [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) :

> Authors must not include more than one main element in a document.
>
> Authors must not include the main element as a descendant of an
> article, aside, footer, header or nav element.
>
> The main element represents the main content of the body of a document
> or application.

So you should use main as a delimiter of your main content of your website and use article or sections inside main as a delimiter of context, here is a sample of how to handle main :

```
<main>

  <h1>Skateboards</h1>
  <p>The skateboard is the way cool kids get around</p>
  
  <article>
    <h2>Longboards</h2>
    <p>Longboards are a type of skateboard with a longer 
       wheelbase and larger, softer wheels.</p>
    <p>... </p>
    <p>... </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Electric Skateboards</h2>
    <p>These no longer require the propelling of the skateboard
       by means of the feet; rather an electric motor propels the board, 
       fed by an electric battery.</p>
    <p>... </p>
    <p>... </p>
  </article>

</main>
```

NB : Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.

Comment: The quote doesn’t include `section`.

Comment: Yes, I still don't get how to get those two elements combined together.

Comment: The answer to your question seems to be no. You should not include main into sections/articles.

Answer (score -1):

The main tag should be for the main content on the page.