# Which one comes first, main tag or section tag?

Tags: html

Should `<section>` tag be inside a `<main>` tag or the other way around? is it ok to make `<main>` tag that includes many `<section>` tags as its descendants? example:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>  
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815584/should-the-main-tag-be-inside-section-tag).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should the <main> tag be inside <section> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815584/should-the-main-tag-be-inside-section-tag)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't agree with divya jyothi. In that example the 'section' is being used to structure the various blocks of the page, whereas it should be used to divide up the CONTENT in an article into meaningful chunks.
Obviously, it's down to personal preferences but here is what I recommend to my clients :

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>[main menu]</nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <article>

                <h1></h1>
                <p>Intro</p>

                <section>
                    <h2>Header for theme of first section</h2>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>Header for theme of second section</h2>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>Header for theme of third section</h2>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </section>

                <aside>
                    Comments directly related to the article
                </aside>
                <aside>
                    Other articles similar to the main article
                </aside>

            </article>

            <aside>
                Block of content not directly related to article ie form to sign up
            </aside>



        </main>
        <nav>[right column menu]</nav>

        <footer>
            <nav>[bottom menu]</nav>
        </footer>       
    </body>
</html>
```

The variations are obviously unlimited but I think it's a good basic template. Read more here https://www.semrush.com/blog/semantic-html5-guide/ and you can visualise your semantic HTML5 structure here https://sitegardien.com/html5viewer/semantichtml5viewer.php

Comment: And you should not put IDs or classes in semantic tags unless it's for the sole purpose as being an anchor

Comment: Presumably your [main menu] in the header is the top navbar menu, and just like you have a [right column menu] after main, you could also have a [left column menu] before main. Also note header, footer are not necessarily one per document, there can be multiples, say one per section, or even one per article.

Comment: Well yes, if the left or right columns are nav menus then they should be outside <main> but if they contain links to, say, articles related to the main content of the page I would put that column in in an <aside> in <main>.

And while, as you say, it is acceptable to have multiple headers and footers in a page I would say don't do it just because you can. If you don't have a real solid reason to put them in, don't do it and keep the semantic structure as simple and clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I just accepted you answer, you are right!

Answer (score 3):

The `<main>` element should contain the main content for our web page and content should be unique to the individual page, and should not appear elsewhere on the site.

`<section>` element is used to represent a group of related content.

You can use `<section>` inside the `<main>` tag.

The ideal structure for HTML Semantic tags is

```
<main id="wrapper">
   <section id="content">
      <article id="post">
                    <header>
                        <h1>HTML Semantic tags</h1>
                        <p>Correctly Use Semantic HTML5 <article>, <main> and <section> 
                        Tags</p>
                    </header>
     <footer>
           <p>Correctly Use Semantic HTML5 <article>, <main> and <section> 
                        Tags</p>
     </footer>

                    <section id="comments">

                        <article>
                            <p>This is my all important comment, please don't delete it. 
                            </p>
                        </article>

                    </section>

                </article>

            </section>

            <aside>
            </aside>

        </main>
```

Comment: According to W3Schools, this is not accurate.
"The content inside the <main> element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms."

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically , you can use your logic here . Section is the part of your website . for example , footer would be a section . Also , any PART of the page is a section. Now you can wrap those section in  or in anything else .. be it only `<body>` tag or

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class wrapper>
      <section>
```

So to say it simple, main first than section :)